# SQL Query - Using Order By in UNION

Tags: sql, ms-access, sorting, sql-order-by, union

How can one programmatically sort a union query when pulling data from two tables? For example,

```
SELECT table1.field1 FROM table1 ORDER BY table1.field1
UNION
SELECT table2.field1 FROM table2 ORDER BY table2.field1
```

Throws an exception

Note: this is being attempted on MS Access Jet database engine

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Sometimes you need to have the `ORDER BY` in each of the sections that need to be combined with `UNION`.

In this case

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT table1.field1 FROM table1 ORDER BY table1.field1
) DUMMY_ALIAS1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
( 
  SELECT table2.field1 FROM table2 ORDER BY table2.field1
) DUMMY_ALIAS2
```

Comment: worked for me when the order by affects the result set (as when using Top x)

Comment: Works great for me...you need to make sure that the outer select has a table alias.  That bit me.

Comment: [I had no problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27799253/23118) using this syntax with Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit) version 11.0.5058.0.

Comment: @Troy: Not sure if we really need a dummy alias. Worked fine for me without alias on Oracle 12g.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I think the first UNION needs the list of columns

Comment: In SSMS you will need to change the sub-queries to `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT` in order to use `ORDER BY` in a sub-query

Comment: IMPORTANT:  in 2014  works with UNION ALL and does not with UNION

Comment: If I don't provide the alias it doesn't work, if i provide the alias its not taking it. I also used 'AS' term for providing alias.

Comment: This is wrong. Order by for union goes after the 2nd select; order by not at outermost level without top/limit is not specified to have any effect.

Answer (score 65):

```
SELECT field1 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT field1 FROM table2
ORDER BY field1
```

Comment: This technically doesn't accomplish what you were logically asking in the original question.

Comment: @Ian Boyd: I take your point but what they are asking makes no logical sense: union operates on sets and sets have no order!

Comment: @onedaywhen The original author wants to concatenate two ordered sets of results. `UNION` does not allow that to happen. There may be another construct to do it. There may not. Either way this answer doesn't technically accomplish what author was asking.

Comment: @Ian Boyd: In SQL, `ORDER BY` is part of a cursor, whereas `UNION` operates on tables, therefore their code cannot work. I cannot see how you can infer the OP's intention from absurd code. Consider that SQL's `UNION` removes duplicates: if these are your "ordered sets of results" `{1, 2, 3} UNION {2, 4, 6}` would the result be `{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}` or `{1, 3, 2, 4, 6}`? We don't know because union of "ordered sets of results" is undefined as regards SQL and the OP hasn't specified.

Comment: I am using MYSQL, I have included the field (Ordering field) in all the select statements.  Then just added Order by by at the end, Works fine for me.

Answer (score 58):

I think this does a good job of explaining.

The following is a UNION query that uses an ORDER BY clause:

```
select supplier_id, supplier_name
from suppliers
where supplier_id > 2000
UNION
select company_id, company_name
from companies
where company_id > 1000
ORDER BY 2;
```

Since the column names are different between the two "select" statements, it is more advantageous to reference the columns in the ORDER BY clause by their position in the result set.

In this example, we've sorted the results by `supplier_name` / `company_name` in ascending order, as denoted by the "ORDER BY 2".

The `supplier_name` / `company_name` fields are in position #2 in the
result set.

Taken from here: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union.php

Answer (score 30):

Using a concrete example:

```
SELECT name FROM Folders ORDER BY name
UNION
SELECT name FROM Files ORDER BY name
```

**Files:**

```
name
=============================
RTS.exe
thiny1.etl
thing2.elt
f.txt
tcpdump_trial_license (1).zip
```

**Folders:**

```
name
============================
Contacts
Desktop
Downloads
Links
Favorites
My Documents
```

**Desired Output:** (results of first select first, i.e. folders first)

```
Contacts
Desktop
Downloads
Favorites
Links
My Documents
f.txt
RTMS.exe
tcpdump_trial_license (1).zip
thiny1.etl
thing2.elt
```

SQL to achieve the desired results:

```
SELECT name 
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS rank, name FROM Folders
    UNION 
    SELECT 2 AS rank, name FROM Files) dt
ORDER BY rank, name
```

Comment: This is the best answer by far

Comment: This is GREAT answer!

Comment: Note - you *must* give the derived table an alias (as shown in this example with `dt`) or it won't work. I was puzzled by this for a little while since I'd omitted that detail to begin with and the error message thrown by SSMS is not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 17):

Here's an example from Northwind 2007:

```
SELECT [Product ID], [Order Date], [Company Name], [Transaction], [Quantity]
FROM [Product Orders]
UNION SELECT [Product ID], [Creation Date], [Company Name], [Transaction], [Quantity]
FROM [Product Purchases]
ORDER BY [Order Date] DESC;
```

The ORDER BY clause just needs to be the last statement, after you've done all your unioning.  You can union several sets together, then put an ORDER BY clause after the last set.

Answer (score 9):

```
(SELECT table1.field1 FROM table1 
UNION
SELECT table2.field1 FROM table2) ORDER BY field1
```

Work?  Remember think sets.  Get the set you want using a union and then perform your operations on it.

Comment: You can also use ordinal values in your order by clause in case the fields you wish to sort on are named differently

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT table1Column1 as col1,table1Column2 as col2
    FROM table1
UNION
(    SELECT table2Column1 as col1, table1Column2 as col2
         FROM table2
)
ORDER BY col1 ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT field1
FROM ( SELECT field1 FROM table1
       UNION
       SELECT field1 FROM table2
     ) AS TBL
ORDER BY TBL.field1
```

(use ALIAS)

Comment: @DisplacedGuy if MJ has a better answer to a question then then any of the above, and in this case the accepted answer clearly has problems, then MJ should be able to and I encourage him to leave new answers

Comment: And btw, MJ's answer is best! (for me at least)

Answer (score 4):

This is the stupidest thing I've ever seen, but it works, and you can't argue with results.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT table1.field1 FROM table1 ORDER BY table1.field1
    UNION
    SELECT table2.field1 FROM table2 ORDER BY table2.field1
) derivedTable
```

The interior of the derived table will not execute on its own, but as a derived table works perfectly fine. I've tried this on SS 2000, SS 2005, SS 2008 R2, and all three work.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it is done

```
select * from 
    (select top 100 percent pointx, pointy from point
     where pointtype = 1
     order by pointy) A
union all
select * from 
    (select top 100 percent pointx, pointy from point
     where pointtype = 2
     order by pointy desc) B
```

Answer (score 2):

Browsing this comment section I came accross two different patterns answering the question. Sadly for SQL 2012, the second pattern doesn't work, so here's my "work around"

---

### Order By on a Common Column

This is the easiest case you can encounter. Like many user pointed out, all you really need to do is add an `Order By` at the end of the query

```
SELECT a FROM table1
UNION
SELECT a FROM table2
ORDER BY field1
```

or

```
SELECT a FROM table1 ORDER BY field1
UNION
SELECT a FROM table2 ORDER BY field1
```

---

### Order By on Different Columns

Here's where it actually gets tricky. Using SQL 2012, I tried the top post and it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT table1.field1 FROM table1 ORDER BY table1.field1
) DUMMY_ALIAS1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
( 
  SELECT table2.field1 FROM table2 ORDER BY table2.field1
) DUMMY_ALIAS2
```

Following the recommandation in the comment I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT table1.field1 FROM table1 ORDER BY table1.field1
) DUMMY_ALIAS1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
( 
  SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT table2.field1 FROM table2 ORDER BY table2.field1
) DUMMY_ALIAS2
```

This code did compile but the `DUMMY_ALIAS1` and `DUMMY_ALIAS2` override the `Order By` established in the `Select` statement which makes this unusable.

The only solution that I could think of, that worked for me was not using a union and instead making the queries run individually and then dealing with them. So basically, not using a `Union` when you want to `Order By`

Answer (score 1):

By using order separately each subset gets order, but not the whole set, which is what you would want uniting two tables.

You should use something like this to have **one** ordered set:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5 FROM 
(SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table1.field3, table1.field4, table1.field5 FROM table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT table2.field1, table2.field2, table2.field3, table2.field4, table2.field5 FROM  table2) 
AS unitedTables ORDER BY field5 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The second table cannot include the table name in the `ORDER BY` clause.

So...

```
SELECT table1.field1 FROM table1 ORDER BY table1.field1
UNION
SELECT table2.field1 FROM table2 ORDER BY field1
```

Does not throw an exception

Comment: What a good question this was. Can you tell whether your version, or the nested one, return the desired results? Or, do they both return the same results? If so, would the (other guy's) nested solution be more performant because it only does ORDER BY once?

Comment: I'm not sure the performance benefit on the Jet engine, but I would say the readability is increased due to the nesting.

Answer (score 0):

If necessary to keep the inner sorting:

```
SELECT 1 as type, field1 FROM table1 
UNION 
SELECT 2 as type, field1 FROM table2 
ORDER BY type, field1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT FIELD1 AS NEWFIELD FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY FIELD1)
UNION
(SELECT FIELD2 FROM TABLE2 ORDER BY FIELD2)
UNION
(SELECT FIELD3 FROM TABLE3 ORDER BY FIELD3) ORDER BY NEWFIELD
```

Try this. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**For Sql Server 2014/2012/Others(Not Checked) :**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT table1.field1 FROM table1 ORDER BY table1.field1
) 
as DUMMY_ALIAS1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
( 
  SELECT table2.field1 FROM table2 ORDER BY table2.field1
) 
as DUMMY_ALIAS2
```

Comment: You get a compile error in 2012 trying this one.  The script will not work for a stored procedure.  You need the top clause.