# Union and order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider a table like

```
tbl_ranks
--------------------------------
family_id | item_id | view_count 
--------------------------------
1           10        101
1           11        112
1           13        109

2           21        101
2           22        112
2           23        109

3           30        101
3           31        112
3           33        109

4           40        101
4           51        112
4           63        109

5           80        101
5           81        112
5           88        109
```

I need to generate a result set with the top two(2) rows for a subset of family ids (say, 1,2,3 and 4) ordered by view count.
I'd like to do something like

```
select top 2 * from tbl_ranks where family_id = 1 order by view_count
union all
select top 2 * from tbl_ranks where family_id = 2 order by view_count
union all
select top 2 * from tbl_ranks where family_id = 3 order by view_count
union all
select top 2 * from tbl_ranks where family_id = 4 order by view_count
```

but, of course, **order by** isn't valid in a **union all** context in this manner. Any suggestions? I know I could run a set of 4 queries, store the results into a temp table and select the contents of that temp as the final result, but I'd rather avoid using a temp table if possible.

Note: in the real app, the number of records per family id is indeterminate, and the view_counts are also not fixed as they appear in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
DECLARE @tbl_ranks TABLE(
        family_id INT,
        item_id INT,
        view_count INT
)

INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 1,10,101
INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 1,11,112
INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 1,13,109

INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 2,21,101
INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 2,22,112
INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 2,23,109

INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 3,30,101
INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 3,31,112
INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 3,33,109

INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 4,40,101
INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 4,51,112
INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 4,63,109

INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 5,80,101
INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 5,81,112
INSERT INTO @tbl_ranks SELECT 5,88,109

SELECT  *
FROm    (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY family_id ORDER BY view_count DESC) MyOrder
            FROM    @tbl_ranks
        ) MyOrders
WHERE   MyOrder <= 2
```

Comment: I modified this to use a CTE instead of the nested select, but otherwise it's perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (select *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY family_id ORDER BY view_count DESC) 'rank'
          from tbl_ranks) x
  WHERE x.rank <= 2
ORDER BY ...
```

The rationale is to assign a ranking, and then filter based on it.

Comment: Should probably use a sub select to access the rank column.

Comment: I don't believe that the rank column is available in the WHERE predicate. Analytics are evaluated *after* predicates, so you need a sub-select for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  tro.*
FROM    family
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 2 *
        FROM    tbl_ranks tr
        WHERE   tr.family_id = family.id
        ORDER BY
                view_count DESC
        ) tro
WHERE   family.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

If you don't have an actual `family` table, you can construct it using a set of unions or a recursive CTE:

```
WITH   family AS
       (
       SELECT  1 AS id
       UNION ALL
       SELECT  2 AS id
       UNION ALL
       SELECT  3 AS id
       UNION ALL
       SELECT  4 AS id
       )
SELECT  tro.*
FROM    family
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 2 *
        FROM    tbl_ranks tr
        WHERE   tr.family_id = family.id
        ORDER BY
                view_count DESC
        ) tro
WHERE   family.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Make sure you have an index on `tbl_ranks (family_id, viewcount)`.

This will be efficient if you have lots of ranks per family, since analytic functions like `ROW_NUMBER` will not use the `TOP` method if used with `PARTITION BY`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can take advantage of analytic functions:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT rank() OVER (PARTITION BY family_id ORDER BY view_count) AS RNK, * FROM ...
     )
WHERE RNK <= 2
ORDER BY ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to tweak your suggested SQL commands a little bit to make it work like you wanted. To bind TOP and ORDER BY you can put the statement inside paranthesis which you select from and give a name (not used here but required).

With the DECLARE and INSERT statements from [Adriaan Stander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1882878/23118) the following

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM @tbl_ranks WHERE family_id = 1 ORDER BY view_count) AS dummy1 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM @tbl_ranks WHERE family_id = 2 ORDER BY view_count) AS dummy2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM @tbl_ranks WHERE family_id = 3 ORDER BY view_count) AS dummy3 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM @tbl_ranks WHERE family_id = 4 ORDER BY view_count) AS dummy4
```

gives

```
family_id   item_id view_count
1   10  101
1   13  109
2   21  101
2   23  109
3   30  101
3   33  109
4   40  101
4   63  109
```