# How to make XML EXPLICIT *NOT* reorder tags alphabetically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am using XML EXPLICIT to generate an XML document that is sent to another application. The tags are Labels/Values and the order is important, since the other app will show the label and the value in the received order.

This an example of the info I using

```
N     |    V
_______________
Objective - XXX
State     - New York
Country   - US
```

and I am expecting to get

```
<X>
   <T>
     <N>Objective</N>
     <V>XXX</V>
   </T>
   <T>
     <N>State</N>
     <V>New York</V>
   </T>
   <T>
     <N>Country</N>
     <V>US</V>
   </T>
</X>
```

however im getting them ordered alphabetically by the N tag

```
<X>
   <T>
     <N>Country</N>
     <V>US</V>
   </T>
   <T>
     <N>Objective</N>
     <V>XXX</V>
   </T>
   <T>
     <N>State</N>
     <V>New York</V>
   </T>

</X>
```

this is the query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[XML]    
 @iPackageId INT,     
 @iUserId INT    
AS    
BEGIN    
 SET NOCOUNT ON    

 DECLARE @iPluginId INT, @iIndex INT, @sLabel VARCHAR(100), @sValue VARCHAR(200), @sField VARCHAR(4000), @sQuery VARCHAR(8000)    

 DECLARE @MySettings TABLE(iIndex INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, iSettingsId INT, sLabel VARCHAR(100), sField VARCHAR(4000))    
 DECLARE @Fields TABLE(sLabel VARCHAR(100), sValue VARCHAR(400))    

 SET @iPluginId = (SELECT iPluginId FROM trnPackage WHERE iPackageId = @iPackageId)    
 SET @iIndex = 1    
 SET @sQuery = ''    

//WE get for the N and a sqlstatement to get the V from the catPluginSettings table, and order them by iDisplayOrder, and insert them in temp MySettings table.
//By executing that sql statement we get the actual value of for V, and save the N and V in @Fields table

 INSERT INTO @MySettings    
 SELECT     
  iSettingsId,sLabel, sField    
 FROM catPluginSettings    
 WHERE iPluginId = @iPluginId    
  AND bActive = 1    
 ORDER BY iDisplayOrder    



 WHILE EXISTS (SELECT iIndex FROM @MySettings)    
 BEGIN    
  SELECT     
   @sLabel = sLabel,     
   @sField = sField + CAST(@iPackageId AS varchar)    
  FROM @MySettings T    
  WHERE iIndex = @iIndex    

  -- GET VALUE FROM sFiled     
  DECLARE @sResult NVARCHAR(400)    

  DECLARE @SelectStatement NVARCHAR(4000)    
  DECLARE @FullStatement NVARCHAR(4000)    
  DECLARE @ParameterList NVARCHAR(500)         

  SET @ParameterList = '@sResult NVARCHAR(400) OUTPUT'         
  SET @FullStatement = @sField     

  EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullStatement, @ParameterList, @sResult = @sResult OUTPUT    
 IF NOT @sLabel IS NULL AND NOT @sResult IS NULL BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO @Fields VALUES (@sLabel ,@sResult)    
 END  
  -- END GET VALUE FROM sField    

  DELETE @MySettings WHERE iIndex = @iIndex    

  SET @iIndex = @iIndex + 1    
 END    



 -- ROOT    
 SELECT  distinct  
  1 as Tag,     
  NULL as Parent,    
  NULL [X!1],     
  BB.iBBId as [X!1!A!element],    
  T.sPckCode as [X!1!B!element],    
  SUBSTRING(cU.sNetLogin, CHARINDEX('\',cU.sNetLogin )+1, LEN(cU.sNetLogin)) as [X!1!C!element],    
  cUR.sFullName as [X!1!D!element],    
 CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, T.dCreationDate) AS VARCHAR)    
   + dbo.PadLeft(CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, T.dCreationDate) AS VARCHAR),2,'0')    
   + dbo.PadLeft(CAST(DATEPART(DAY, T.dCreationDate) AS VARCHAR),2,'0')     
   + dbo.PadLeft(CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, T.dCreationDate) AS VARCHAR),2,'0')    
   + dbo.PadLeft(CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, T.dCreationDate) AS VARCHAR),2,'0')   
AS [X!1!E!element],    
  cP.sAppShortName as [X!1!F!element],    
  CONVERT (DECIMAL (16, 2), T.mAmountUSD) as [X!1!G!element], ---> CAST a 2 Decimales <--    
  NULL AS [T!2!N!element],    
  NULL AS [T!2!V!element]    
 FROM trnPackage T    
 INNER JOIN trnPkgBB BB ON T.iPackageId = BB.iPackageId    
 INNER JOIN relPackageUser R ON T.iPackageId = R.iPackageId --AND R.bIsSysAdmin = 0 AND R.bIsBackupUser = 0    
 INNER JOIN catUser cU ON R.iUserId = cU.iUserId      
 INNER JOIN catUser cUR ON T.iUserId = cUR.iUserId     
 INNER JOIN catPlugin cP ON T.iPluginId = cP.iPluginId    
 WHERE (T.iPackageId = @iPackageId AND R.iUserId = @iUserId)    
  AND (BB.iPackageId = @iPackageId AND BB.iApproverId = @iUserId)    
  AND BB.iBBStatusId <> (SELECT iStatusId FROM catStatus WHERE sStatusName = 'Completed')    

-- EXTRA INFO    
 UNION     
 SELECT     
  2 AS Tag,    
  1 AS Parent,    
  NULL,    
  NULL,     
  NULL,    
  NULL,    
  NULL,    
  NULL,    
  NULL,     
  NULL,    
  sLabel,    
  sValue    
 FROM @Fields T    
 FOR XML EXPLICIT    
    select * from @Fields
END
```

Comment: `UNION` will cause a `SORT` to get rid of duplicates (and you have `distinct` in there as well). But if you need a specific `ORDER BY` you have to add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see an order by in your final output...

Without it you can't control the order the xml is generated in.

See this question if you don't know how to apply an order by to your union: [SQL Query - Using Order By in UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213851/sql-query-using-order-by-in-union)

Comment: `FOR XML EXPLICIT` requires you to "explicitly" order the results.