# How to select distinct values from 2 tables with sort in one query?

Tags: sql, distinct

I have

- table1 : `country`, `theOrderColumn1`
- table2 : `country`, `theOrderColumn2`

I want to join DISTINCT `country` from these two SELECT statements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `country` FROM `table1` ORDER BY `theOrderColumn1`
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT `country` FROM `table2` ORDER BY `theOrderColumn2`
```

Example:

`table1 (country, theOrderColumn1): (uk, 1), (usa, 2)`
`table2 (country, theOrderColumn2): (france, 1), (uk, 2)`

I want this result:

```
france
uk
usa
```

Answer (score 40):

```
select distinct country
from (
    select country, theOrderColumn from table1
    union all
    select country, theOrderColumn from table2
) a 
order by theOrderColumn
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select country, theOrderColumn from (
select distinct t1.country as country, t1.theOrderColumn as theOrderColumn from table t1
union
select distinct t2.country as country, t2.theOrderColumn as theOrderColumn from table t2) t3
order by theOrderColumn
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve order given by `theOrderColumn1` and `theOrderColumn2` at the same time, you can use the column index to specify the `ORDER BY` column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT country FROM (
(
    SELECT country AS c, theOrderColumn1 AS d FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT country AS c, theOrderColumn2 AS d FROM table2
) ORDER BY 2)
```

Take a look at the answers to this question: [SQL Query - Using Order By in UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213851/851811)

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.country,a.theOrderColumn
(
select country,theOrderColumn
from table1
union
select country,theOrderColumn
from table2
) a
order by a.theOrderColumn
```

Though you will get duplicates if theOrderColumn is different in table 1 and table 2.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are wanting and how you want to join the two tables together.  If you are joining based on "theOrderColumn", then the query would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT country 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.theOrderColumn = table2.theOrderColumn 
ORDER BY theOrderColumn
```

If you want to join across country (which wouldn't make sense as the country would be identical in both tables) then you could swap out "country" in the join clause.

Also, depending on your SQL dialect spoken by your DBMS, your mileage may vary with the above query.  Can you clarify more of what you are after?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!