# mysql having problems with UNION query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cannot seem to get a result for the following query, the following query return NULL

**query union**

```
"SELECT isbn    

    FROM ".TBL_BOOKS." 

    WHERE rank < 200000 AND rank IS NOT NULL 
    AND lowest_new_price < amazon_new_price/100*80 
    AND amazon_new_price < 9999 
    AND ROUND((amazon_new_price/100*80) - lowest_new_price) > (lowest_new_price/100*".MARGIN.") 

UNION 

SELECT isbn 

    FROM ".TBL_BOOKS." 

    WHERE rank < 200000 AND rank IS NOT NULL 
    AND lowest_used_price < amazon_used_price/100*80 
    AND amazon_used_price < 9999 
    AND amazon_used_price < amazon_new_price 
    AND ROUND((amazon_used_price/100*80) - lowest_used_price) > (lowest_used_price/100*".MARGIN.") 

ORDER BY rank ASC";
```

but the two quires work fine on their own

**query 1**

```
"SELECT isbn    

    FROM ".TBL_BOOKS." 

    WHERE rank < 200000 AND rank IS NOT NULL 
    AND lowest_new_price < amazon_new_price/100*80 
    AND amazon_new_price < 9999 
    AND ROUND((amazon_new_price/100*80) - lowest_new_price) > (lowest_new_price/100*".MARGIN.") 
ORDER BY rank ASC";
```

**query 2**

```
"   SELECT isbn 

        FROM ".TBL_BOOKS." 

        WHERE rank < 200000 AND rank IS NOT NULL 
        AND lowest_used_price < amazon_used_price/100*80 
        AND amazon_used_price < 9999 
        AND amazon_used_price < amazon_new_price 
        AND ROUND((amazon_used_price/100*80) - lowest_used_price) > (lowest_used_price/100*".MARGIN.") 

ORDER BY rank ASC";
```

If I broke up the union and ran both queries separately I would have no problems, but for some reason the UNION query does not work, what could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work? Tell us more exactly what happens. Is there a mysql error? a PHP error?

Comment: Note that `union` removes duplicates.  To keep duplicates (and save the expensive duplicate removal) use `union all`

Comment: @Andomar Thanks you just solved another problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think - when you use an 'order by' clause in a union - then the 'order by' parameter has to be one of the fields returned by the individual queries.

Comment: Yes when I answered the earlier question about this, there was a rank field and another field to determine to flag if this was new or used (though you may not need that one). I only moved the rank to outside of the individual selects so you could get a sort across the union. If you leave the sorts in the individual selects you will only have sorts within those portions of the result set.

Comment: @Mike this is a similiar function, which only returns the isbn number

Comment: There's another topic dealing with this that might have some useful information, too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213851/sql-query-using-order-by-in-union