# SQL Select with 3 table from 2 databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables with some banners info and i need to select all the banners from all of them by CompanyID.

The tables are:

```
BannerCompany (AdminMaster.dbo.BannerUnidades)
Banner        (AdminMaster.dbo.Banner)
BannerClient  (AdminHotSite.dbo.Banner)
```

- The first table (**BannerCompany**) has *CompanyID* and *BannerID* and is linked to the table **Banner** by *BannerID*;
- The second table (**Banner**) has *BannerID* and all the rest of the banner info;
- The third table (**BannerClient**) is another table where i have other banners also with *CompanyID* and *BannerID* (This *BannerID* from table **BannerClient** is different from the *BannerID* from table **Banner**).

What i need is select the banners on **BannerCompany** and link them with **Banner** by *BannerID* with a **WHERE** on **BannerCompany.BannerCompanyID** and then select the banners from **BannerClient** with the same where but now on **BannerClient.BannerCompanyID**.

Now, i can select the banners from the first and the second but i can't find a way to put the third table on the game.

All the tables have the same columns with the same name.

My code so far:

```
SELECT * FROM AdminMaster.dbo.BannerUnidades AS bUnidade
INNER JOIN AdminMaster.dbo.Banner  AS bMaster ON bUnidade.BannerID = bMaster.BannerID
INNER JOIN AdminHotSite.dbo.Banner AS bHS     ON bHS.BannerPrincipal = 1
WHERE bHS.UnidadeCodEmitente = 45471
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the two different DB servers linked?btw which tables are on which db? your question does not indicate this

Comment: What did you try and what happened when you did so?

Comment: The first two tables are on one DB and the third is in another.

When i try it, it only bring me records from the first or the second when i change my WHERE.

Comment: Please post your SQL statement.

Comment: are the two servers linked?

Comment: gh9, sorry, they are in the same server

Comment: oh perfect. Put your sql query up i will post some pseudo code that will do what you want

Comment: the sql is correct what is the execution result?

Comment: I need to join the columns, i receive the results from the first and second table and then i have all the columns again for the third table.

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img841/2731/8gxq.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you a starting point.

Get list of all banners for the specific company:

```
SELECT bMaster.BannerID, bHS.BannerTitulo 
FROM AdminMaster.dbo.BannerUnidades AS bUnidade
INNER JOIN AdminMaster.dbo.Banner  AS bMaster ON bUnidade.BannerID = bMaster.BannerID
WHERE bUnidade.UnidadeCodEmitente = 45471

UNION ALL

SELECT bHS.BannerID, bHS.BannerTitulo 
FROM AdminHotSite.dbo.Banner AS bHS
WHERE bHS.UnidadeCodEmitente = 45471 AND bHS.BannerPrincipal = 1
```

Get list of all banners for the specific company with custom ORDER BY:

```
SELECT bMaster.BannerID, bHS.BannerTitulo, SortOrder = 1, BannerOrdem 
FROM AdminMaster.dbo.BannerUnidades AS bUnidade
INNER JOIN AdminMaster.dbo.Banner  AS bMaster ON bUnidade.BannerID = bMaster.BannerID
WHERE bUnidade.UnidadeCodEmitente = 45471

UNION ALL

SELECT bHS.BannerID, bHS.BannerTitulo, SortOrder = 2,  BannerOrdem 
FROM AdminHotSite.dbo.Banner AS bHS
WHERE bHS.UnidadeCodEmitente = 45471 AND bHS.BannerPrincipal = 1
ORDER BY SortOrder, BannerOrdem
```

Comment: What if i want to order the result on both selects ?

Both tables have a column called BannerOrdem and i want first order by the first select and then for the second

Comment: Look here on how to use ORDER BY in UNION: http://stackoverflow.com/q/213851/327165