# Get data from 3 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables in my Oracle DB, namely

AMI2.AMI2_RESOURCE_ITEM_JN

```
  ID                               NUMBER(18,0)          NULL,
  TYPE_CODE                        VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)     NULL,
  USER_JN                          VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)     NOT NULL,
```

AMI2_RESOURCE_ITEM_DOTNET_JN

```
  ID                               NUMBER(18,0)          NULL,
  NAAM                             VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)    NULL,
  USER_JN                          VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)     NOT NULL,
```

AMI2.AMI2_RESOURCE_ITEM_WAARDE_JN

```
  ID                               NUMBER(18,0)          NULL,
  WAARDE                           CLOB                  NULL,
  USER_JN                          VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)     NOT NULL,
```

What I need is to join this tables and get the distinct user_jn of all tables.

AMI2.AMI2_RESOURCE_ITEM_JN

```
ID   TYPE_CODE      USER_JN
167  DOTNET_GLOBAL  DG3\PAULB
168  DOTNET_GLOBAL  DG3\JOSBRA
169  DOTNET_GLOBAL  DG3\JOSBRA
170  DOTNET_GLOBAL  DG3\RONASS
171  DOTNET_GLOBAL  DG3\JOSBRA
199  DOTNET_GLOBAL  DG3\RUIMAR
162  DOTNET_GLOBAL  DG3\DIMITRI
201  DOTNET_GLOBAL  DG3\RUIMAR
204  DOTNET_GLOBAL  DG3\RUIMAR
207  DOTNET_GLOBAL  DG3\DIMITRI
```

AMI2_RESOURCE_ITEM_DOTNET_JN

```
ID   NAAM             USER_J
167  MaatregelWaarde  DG3\JOSBRA
168  MaatregelWaarde  DG3\JOSBRA 
169  MaatregelWaarde  DG3\JOSBRA 
170  MaatregelWaarde  DG3\JOSBRA 
171  MaatregelWaarde  DG3\JOSBRA 
199  MaatregelWaarde  DG3\RUIMAR 
162  MaatregelWaarde  DG3\RUIMAR
```

AMI2.AMI2_RESOURCE_ITEM_WAARDE_JN

```
ID   Waarde     USER_J
149 (HUGECLOB)  DG3\JOSBRA
150 (HUGECLOB)  DG3\JOSBRA
151 (HUGECLOB)  DG3\JOSBRA
152 (HUGECLOB)  DG3\JOSBRA
153 (HUGECLOB)  DG3\JOSBRA
158 (HUGECLOB)  DG3\RUIMAR
```

So, with this 3 tables, I need to get

```
USER_J
DG3\DIMITRI
DG3\JOSBRA
DG3\PAULB
DG3\RONASS
DG3\RUIMAR
```

I'm not very good at this, so I don't even know where to start.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT USER_JN FROM AMI2.AMI2_RESOURCE_ITEM_JN
UNION
SELECT USER_JN FROM AMI2_RESOURCE_ITEM_DOTNET_JN
UNION
SELECT USER_JN FROM AMI2.AMI2_RESOURCE_ITEM_WAARDE_JN
```

Hint: The result of a `UNION` is distinct by default. *(Use `UNION ALL` if you want duplicates at some point.)*

When it comes to sorting the result, refer to [SQL Query - Using Order By in UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213851/sql-query-using-order-by-in-union)

Comment: Thanks. That works. Just one more thing, what if I want to get the results without the DG3\?

Comment: I managed to get this, SELECT SUBSTR(USER_JN, INSTR(USER_JN, '\') + 1) from ami2_resource_item_jn
UNION
SELECT SUBSTR(USER_JN, INSTR(USER_JN, '\') + 1) from ami2_resource_item_dotnet_jn
UNION
SELECT SUBSTR(USER_JN, INSTR(USER_JN, '\') + 1) from AMI2_RESOURCE_ITEM_WAARDE_JN;