# Order by on single column

Tags: sql, informix

I have Informix code:

```
select data as DATA from (
(select distinct('Date|Message_Type|Total') as data,0 as sort from dual)
union
(select 'dt: '||day||'|'||trim(msg_type)||'|'||nvl(round(total,2),0) as data,1 as sort from weekly_report_1)
                 )order by sort)
```

Output:

```
data1
Date|Message_Type|Total
dt: 02/10/2015|1440|0.00
dt: 02/10/2015|Total|-26290965.84
dt: 02/11/2015|1240|-23550538.87
dt: 02/11/2015|1440|0.00
dt: 02/11/2015|Total|-23550538.87
dt: 02/10/2015|1240|-26290965.84
dt: 02/12/2015|1240|-24181913.23
dt: 02/14/2015|Total|0.00
dt: 02/12/2015|1440|0.00
dt: 02/12/2015|Total|-24181913.23
dt: 02/13/2015|1240|-24611999.80
dt: 02/13/2015|1440|0.00
dt: 02/13/2015|Total|-24611999.80
dt: 02/14/2015|1240|0.00
dt: 02/14/2015|1440|0.00
```

When I am trying to do the following:

```
select * from(
select data as DATA1 from (
(select distinct('Date|Message_Type|Total') as data,0 as sort from dual)
union
(select 'dt: '||day||'|'||trim(msg_type)||'|'||nvl(round(total,2),0) as data,1 as sort from weekly_report_1)
                 )order by sort) order by DATA1;
```

I am getting:

> Error: General error.Syntax error (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFD4CC)

I need to sort the table.

Comment: Selecting 1 as `sort` and then ordering by `sort` is guaranteed not to sort. Whatever your data is.

Comment: Not tested, but as a quick punt (assuming you want to sort by date ...

`select distinct('Date|Message_Type|Total') as data from dual
union (select 'dt: '||day||'|'||trim(msg_type)||'|'||nvl(round(total,2),0) as data from weekly_report_1 order by day)`

Comment: Actually, trying that out on an Oracle database, the problem may be that you can't specify an order by on the subselect in a union.  However, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213851/sql-query-using-order-by-in-union) article has a work round ... `select distinct('Date|Message_Type|Total') as data from dual
union
select * from ( select 'dt: '||day||'|'||trim(msg_type)||'|'||nvl(round(total,2),0) as data from weekly_report_1 order by day );`

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one ORDER BY clause.  You don't need the second level of sub-query.

```
SELECT data AS Data1 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT('Date|Message_Type|Total') AS Data,
               0 AS Sort
          FROM dual
        UNION
        SELECT 'dt: '||day||'|'||trim(msg_type)||'|'||nvl(round(total,2),0) AS Data,
               1 AS Sort
          FROM weekly_report_1
       ) AS AnyName
ORDER BY Sort, Data1;
```

Unless you have a seriously archaic (many years overdue for replacement) version of Informix, you can sort by a column that isn't listed in the select-list.  If you do have a sufficiently archaic version of Informix that this doesn't work, you'll need to select the `Sort` value too.  Or you can rely on `Date` preceding `dt` in the code set you're using and simply omit the ordering on `Sort`.