# Can not order by when using UNION in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union, sql-order-by

I have this query that is working if I do no do UNION:

```sql
SELECT t1.offer_id, t1.cpv_id, t1.type,
FROM `offer_cpv` t1
JOIN `offer` t2     ON t1.offer_id = t2.id
JOIN `company` t3   ON t2.cmpid = t3.id
WHERE t1.cpv_id = :cpvid
AND t3.status IN (4, 6)
GROUP BY t1.offer_id
ORDER BY t1.type
```

Key part is that I am doing `ORDER BY t1.type`. But if I use UNION (and I have to) my query breaks saying:

> Unknown column 't1.type' in 'order clause'

Here are my UNION tries that do not work:

```sql
SELECT t1.offer_id, t1.cpv_id, t1.type,
FROM `offer_cpv` t1
JOIN `offer` t2    ON t1.offer_id = t2.id
JOIN `company` t3  ON t2.cmpid = t3.id
WHERE t1.cpv_id = :cpvid
AND t3.status IN (4, 6)
GROUP BY t1.offer_id
ORDER BY t1.type

UNION

SELECT t1.offer_id, t1.cpv_id, t1.type,
FROM `offer_cpv` t1
JOIN `offer` t2      ON t1.offer_id = t2.id
JOIN `company_2` t3  ON t2.cmpid = t3.id
WHERE t1.cpv_id = :cpvid
AND t3.status IN (4, 6)
GROUP BY t1.offer_id

ORDER BY t1.type
```

And:

```sql
SELECT t1.offer_id, t1.cpv_id, t1.type,
FROM `offer_cpv` t1
JOIN `offer` t2    ON t1.offer_id = t2.id
JOIN `company` t3  ON t2.cmpid = t3.id
WHERE t1.cpv_id = :cpvid
AND t3.status IN (4, 6)
GROUP BY t1.offer_id

UNION

SELECT t1.offer_id, t1.cpv_id, t1.type,
FROM `offer_cpv` t1
JOIN `offer` t2      ON t1.offer_id = t2.id
JOIN `company_2` t3  ON t2.cmpid = t3.id
WHERE t1.cpv_id = :cpvid
AND t3.status IN (4, 6)
GROUP BY t1.offer_id

ORDER BY t1.type
```

Can I somehow do this UNION but order results by type. I am ordering by type because I need to get output like this:

```
<h2> Results of type 1 from both tables: </h2>
<div> Result 1 from **first** table </div>
<div> Result 2 from first table </div>
<div> Result 1 from **second** table </div>
<div> Result 2 from second table </div>
<h2> Results of type 2 from both tables: </h2>
<div> Result 1 from **first** table </div>
<div> Result 2 from first table </div>
<div> Result 1 from **second** table </div>
<div> Result 2 from second table </div>
```

Later I will have to add one more column in ORDER BY clause: t1.rank, so I can order first by type then by rank too !

Comment: you need an outer query ... `select x.offer_id, x.cpv_id, x.type from ( here is the union query)x order by x.type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

> This kind of ORDER BY cannot use column references that include a
>   table name (that is, names in tbl_name.col_name format). Instead,
>   provide a column alias in the first SELECT statement and refer to the
>   alias in the ORDER BY. (Alternatively, refer to the column in the
>   ORDER BY using its column position. However, use of column positions
>   is deprecated.)

So basically you need to (i) create alias for the columns that you need to sort in the *first* query (ii) use the alias in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT t1.offer_id, t1.cpv_id, t1.type AS type_column --, t1.rank as rank_column
FROM `offer_cpv` t1
JOIN `offer` t2 ON t1.offer_id = t2.id
JOIN `company` t3 ON t2.cmpid = t3.id
WHERE t1.cpv_id = :cpvid AND t3.status IN (4, 6)
GROUP BY t1.offer_id

UNION

SELECT t1.offer_id, t1.cpv_id, t1.type --, t1.rank
FROM `offer_cpv` t1
JOIN `offer` t2 ON t1.offer_id = t2.id
JOIN `company_2` t3 ON t2.cmpid = t3.id
WHERE t1.cpv_id = :cpvid AND t3.status IN (4, 6)
GROUP BY t1.offer_id

ORDER BY type_column --, rank_column
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I used column position, but I see it it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can only order on the whole `UNION`. Remove the first `ORDER BY` alias both t1.type to something else, like "mytype". Then change the second `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY mytype`.

See here:

[SQL Query - Using Order By in UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213851/sql-query-using-order-by-in-union)

Comment: I do not understand, can you show code example please ?

Comment: This example workded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213851/sql-query-using-order-by-in-union . Thanks!