# Particular MySql Query

Tags: mysql

Having the following tables

```
Post(*id, name, description, cat, publish_date)
Category(*id, name)
```

It is possible in ONE query to get (max) the first N element of each different category?

Assuming that N=3, i'd need the following result:

Result set:

```
["1", "Name1","Descr","cat1"]
["2", "Name1","Descr","cat1"]
["3", "Name1","Descr","cat1"]
["10","Name1","Descr","cat2"]
["20","Name1","Descr","cat2"]
["22","Name1","Descr","cat2"]
["25","Name1","Descr","cat3"]
["30","Name1","Descr","cat3"]
["19","Name1","Descr","cat3"]
```

And so on.

I need this, to get the first N article of EACH category, with one query (so without ask for a specific category but for all category in table)

It is possible? If yes what's the right query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will do what you need. If any category has less than 3 post it will still work.

```
SELECT P.id,P.name,P.description,C.name 
FROM Post P
LEFT JOIN Category C
ON P.type = C.id
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(P.id,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ids) FROM
            (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id),',',3) as ids
                FROM Post 
                GROUP BY type
            ) AS foo
        GROUP BY ''
    )
)
```

Here is a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5dd6/1)

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment and updated question:

```
SELECT P.id,P.name,P.description,P.publish_date,C.name 
FROM Post P
LEFT JOIN Category C
ON P.type = C.id
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(P.id,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ids) FROM
            (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY publish_date DESC),',',3) as ids
                FROM Post
                GROUP BY type      
            ) AS foo
        GROUP BY ''
    )
)
```

Comment: How does this query change if want to order post by date, so i can get the last 3 post of each category?

Comment: Where is the date column? In the `Post` table?

Comment: Yes, the name is publish_date

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION` to join multiple queries into one. This assumes that you know what `type` you are selecting for each set.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE type='Type1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
) DUMMY1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE type='Type2' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
) DUMMY2

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE type='Type3' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
) DUMMY3
```

The `DUMMY` table aliases are needed to [allow ordering within each subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3394454/482115).

Comment: Type is stored in other table, there is a way to do this query with a loop or something to query for all types?

Comment: You can `JOIN` this table to the other table for each subquery. Ex: `SELECT * FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.id=T2.id WHERE T2.type='Type3' ORDER BY T1.id DESC LIMIT 3`

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not what I mean. I edit the post, please check the correction. Thank you very much for your help.